# Can we merge this both tag [sharedpreferences] and [android-sharedpreferences]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I noticed that [sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences) and [android-sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sharedpreferences)   both tags are  used for [**`SharedPreferences`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

[sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences)

- `SharedPreferences` allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types in Android applications. It can be used either inside a single app or shared between multiple apps

[android-sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sharedpreferences)

- `SharedPreferences` allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types in Android applications. It can be used either inside a single app or shared between multiple apps.

I propose merging the tags [android-sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sharedpreferences) and [sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences), because Both the tags are used for question related to **`sharedpreferences`**

Questions tagged [sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences) :    5,575 questions
Questions tagged [android-sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sharedpreferences)   :    569 questions